# Get sum of a range in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have excel range B1:B4 which has formulas and updates on values from cell A1 which has a current value of 'x'.

Now I want to write a formula in A2 to sum values in B1:B4, if A1 had a value 'y'

I tried using SUMIFS and SUBSTITUTE together but that didnt work.

Example:
The formula in B1:B4 is A1+1

Value in A1 = 2. The sum of B1:B4 would be 12.

Now, need to write a formula in A2 that will return the sum(B1:B4) if value in A1 had been 1, which would be 8.

Comment: `=IF(A1="y",SUM(B1:B4),"")`?

Comment: A1="y" will return FALSE. Because A1 has a value of x.
That won't work here, right?

Comment: in your question you state: `Now I want to write a formula in A2 to sum values in B1:B4, if A1 had a value 'y'`  That is what the formula does.  When A1 is 'y' it will sum otherwise it will be blank.

Comment: Formulas that reference one cell, will need to have that cell replaced.  You cannot effect the formula in another cell from a different cell.  There is no formula that you can put in A2 that will change the value of B1:B4.  So the best you can do is deal with the results in A1.

Comment: Hope the update to question with an example explains what I am trying to do

Comment: Your question still doesn't really make sense. By `if A1 had a value 'y'`, does the `'y'` in this context mean any number? In that case then use the first comment that @Scott Craner gave you but take out the quotes in `A1="y"` and change it to `A1=y` where y is the number (which is what he meant in his second comment)

Comment: @Kairu "IF" formula tests a condition; so "A1=y" will return FALSE.

Problem Statement: SUM range B1:B4 takes input from cell A1. It updates every time we change the value in A1.

Now we need a formula where we don't have to manually change the value in input cell A1 to have the updated SUM of B1:B2

Comment: Then just ’sum(B1:B4)’?